# <? extends > Java syntax

Tags: java, generics

This code:

```
List<? extends Reader> weirdList;
weirdList.add(new BufferedReader(null));
```

has a compile error of

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Reader) in the type 
>   List is not applicable  for the
>   arguments (BufferedReader)

Why? BufferedReader extends reader, so why isn't that a "match"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics WildCard Question: List<? extends A>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495383/java-generics-wildcard-question-list-extends-a)

Comment: (FWIW, what you want here is `List<Reader>`, not `List<? extends Reader>`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the variable you gave:

```
List<? extends Reader> weirdList;
```

All of the following assignments are valid:

```
weirdList = new ArrayList<Reader>();
weirdList = new ArrayList<FileReader>();
weirdList = new ArrayList<BufferedReader>();
weirdList = new ArrayList<InputStreamReader>();
```

Hopefully this explains your compile error. What you're trying makes sense if `weirdList` holds a value of type `ArrayList<BufferedReader>`, but doesn't make sense for a value of type `ArrayList<FileReader>`. Since a variable of type `List<? extends Reader>` can hold a value of either type (and more!), Java calls that an error.

Generics in Java are hard to get your head around. You can think of the `List<? extends Reader>` type as being mostly useful for assignment or parameter types in methods so that they can accept a wide variety of types. For "regular use", you're probably better off with a "bare" generic like `List<Reader>` or even `List<BufferedReader>`.

Answer (score 6):

When the compiler sees `<? extends Reader>`, then it assumes that it could be *any* type that is or extends `Reader`.  It could be something that is imcompatible with `BufferedReader`, such as `StringReader`.  So if the generic type in the class definition shows up in the parameter of a method such as `add`, and the type of the instance has something like `<? extends Something>`, the compiler must disallow it for type safety reasons.  In this example, it *could* be `List<StringReader>`, so you shouldn't be able to add a `BufferedReader` here.

Answer (score 6):

`List<? extends Reader> weirdList` can hold reference to any type of `List` that stores any type of `Reader`. So it is possible that

```
List<? extends Reader> weirdList1 = new ArrayList<BufferedReader>();
List<? extends Reader> weirdList2 = new ArrayList<FileReader>();
```

If Java would allow you to add `BufferedReader` to `weirdList1` it would also have to let you add `BufferedReader` to `weirdList2` (reference type is the same) which is not suppose to happen since `weirdList2` should store only `FileReader`s.