# Using reflection to invoke Type parameterized methods

Tags: java, reflection, google-cloud-dataflow

The google cloud dataflow sdk has a class that registers Coders for different Avro types.

```
CoderRegistry cr = p.getCoderRegistry();
cr.registerStandardCoders();
cr.registerCoder(Row.class, AvroCoder.of(Row.class));
cr.registerCoder(Destination.class, AvroCoder.of(Destination.class));
cr.registerCoder(Device.class, AvroCoder.of(Device.class));
cr.registerCoder(Location.class, AvroCoder.of(Location.class));
cr.registerCoder(Source.class, AvroCoder.of(Source.class));
cr.registerCoder(DimensionalMetric.class, AvroCoder.of(DimensionalMetric.class));
cr.registerCoder(DimensionSet.class, AvroCoder.of(DimensionSet.class));
cr.registerCoder(MetricSet.class, AvroCoder.of(MetricSet.class));
```

But as you can imagine this gets pretty cumbersome and I would like to use java reflection API to automatically register all classes in the package `com.brightcove.rna.model`. I imagine this would look something like this:

```
void registerAllModels(Pipeline p) {
    CoderRegistry cr = p.getCoderRegistry();
    Reflections r = new Reflections("com.brightcove.rna.model");
    Set<Class<? extends IndexedRecord>> classes = r.getSubTypesOf(IndexedRecord.class);
    for (Class<? extends IndexedRecord> clazz : classes) {
        cr.registerCoder(clazz, AvroCoder.of(clazz));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide the error message or describe the erroneous behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a compile error in the following line:

```
cr.registerCoder(clazz, AvroCoder.of(clazz));
```

The error is:

```
The method registerCoder(Class<?>, Class<?>) in the type CoderRegistry is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#1-of ? extends IndexedRecord>, AvroCoder<capture#2-of ? extends IndexedRecord>).
```

Basically, the issue is that Java compiler cannot infer that the wildcard types on both parameters are the same, and is reporting an error. This is a common Java issue, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495383/java-generics-wildcard-question-list-extends-a) question, for example.

A fix is the following, which may require you to suppress compiler warnings about raw types and an unchecked conversion:

```
  cr.registerCoder(clazz, (Coder) AvroCoder.of(clazz.newInstance().getSchema()));
```

This fixes two problems:

- Ensures `registerCoder(Class<T>, Coder<T>)` is used instead of the overloaded `registerCoder(Class<?>, Class<?>)`.
- `AvroCoder.of(Class<T>)` uses Avro's `ReflectData.get().getSchema()` to generate a schema, which may not work on all types, such as `GenericRecord`. An alternative is to construct the coder via `AvroCoder.of(Schema)` and get the schema from the automatically-generated class.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that a little more reading up on the error message that I was getting helped me reach the root of the problem.

```
AnalyticsPipeline.java:110: error: no suitable method found for registerCoder(Class<CAP#1>,AvroCoder<CAP#2>)
            cr.registerCoder(clazz, AvroCoder.of(clazz));
              ^
    method CoderRegistry.registerCoder(Class<?>,Class<?>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T#1 exist so that AvroCoder<T#1> conforms to Class<?>)
    method CoderRegistry.registerCoder(Class<?>,CoderFactory) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T#1 exist so that AvroCoder<T#1> conforms to CoderFactory)
    method CoderRegistry.<T#2>registerCoder(Class<T#2>,Coder<T#2>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
        inferred: CAP#3
        equality constraints(s): CAP#3,CAP#1)
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>of(Class<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>registerCoder(Class<T#2>,Coder<T#2>)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2,CAP#3 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends IndexedRecord from capture of ? extends IndexedRecord
    CAP#2 extends IndexedRecord from capture of ? extends IndexedRecord
    CAP#3 extends IndexedRecord from capture of ? extends IndexedRecord
```

As stated above, javac thinks that the types of the arguments don't match (correctly so as I have provided no information to that fact). My solution turned out to be a fairly simple modification. By adding a helper function that fixes the type.

```
void registerCoders(Pipeline p) {
        CoderRegistry cr = p.getCoderRegistry();
        Reflections r = new Reflections("com.brightcove.rna.model");
        Set<Class<? extends IndexedRecord>> classes = r.getSubTypesOf(IndexedRecord.class);
        for (Class<? extends IndexedRecord> clazz : classes) {
            registerAvroType(cr, clazz);
        }
    }

    <T extends IndexedRecord> void registerAvroType(CoderRegistry cr, Class<T> clazz) {
        cr.registerCoder(clazz, AvroCoder.of(clazz));
    }
```

I was able to convey to the compiler that the types are indeed the same and the problem was resolved.